# Client-side validation not working when enabled in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am building site using .NET MVC 5.

I have a ViewModel That contains the following

```
public class ContactPageModel
{
    public string Selection{ get; set; }
    public string MonthlyCost { get; set; }

    public ContactInfo Contact { get; set; }
}
```

My Data Annotations are in the ContactInfo

```
public class ContactInfo
{
    [Display(Name = "First Name: ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name Required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name: ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name Required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State: ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State Required")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Number: ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number Required")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email: ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Required")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Best Contact Time: ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Best Contact Time Required")]
    public string BestContractTime { get; set; }
}
```

How do I set the data annotations up properly so that they are properly used by the view?

Here is some of my view code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I do have client validation enabled with the ClientValidationEnabled and the UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled keys in the web.config.

I get no validation message. I assume it is because I have the ContactInfo class nested withing the ContactPageModel class.

Comment: What isn't working? The markup you showed looks fine. Have you [enabled client-side validation](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/bcWO151212-How-to-Enable-and-Disable-Client-Side-Validation-in-MVC.html)?

Comment: Carrie. See edits a the end.

Comment: Have you included the scripts in your view (shown in the article I linked)?

Comment: Client side validation will only work if your form elements are inside a @using Html.BeginForm block

Comment: To extend what @ste-fu said, specifically, jquery-validate only hooks to elements nested within a `<form>` element.

Comment: equally important though is that unobtrusive validation data attributes will not be emitted by the view without it

Comment: jquery.validate.unobtrusive was missing from my bundle. Thanks Carrie.

Comment: @CarrieKendall - you should post this as an answer since it seems to have solved the problem.